# Pointers; Simple Allocation of An Array

Tags: c++

I get an error under "int dArray[size]" saying that size needs to be a constant. Can someone explain what that means exactly?

I want it to be an array of size 4 and output 1, 3, 5, and 7.

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int *AllocateArray(int size, int value){
int dArray[size];
for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++){
    dArray[i] = value;
    value + 2;
}
}

int main(){

AllocateArray(4, 1);
}
```

Solved:

Here is the code that ended up working.

```
#include <iostream> 

 using namespace std; 

int *AllocateArray(int size, int value){
int * Array = new int[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    Array[i] = value;
    value = value + 2;
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    cout << Array[i] << endl;
}
return Array;
}

int main(){

int *dArray = AllocateArray(4, 1);

}
```

Comment: I guess you want to return dArray in AllocateArray

Comment: Now you've entered the world of memory leakage.  You didn't `delete[]` the array you allocated.  Go with `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `int dArray[size]` size is not a constant value.  Because of that you are getting that error.  What you probably wanted to do was make a new array using a pointer and new like:

```
int * dArray = new int[size];
```

Comment: @TerikBrunson Good luck with the memory leaks.

Answer (score 2):

C++ requires that the size of arrays are determined at compile-time. As `size` is determined at runtime, the compiler complains.

If you are interested in having array-like behaviour with a size unknown at compile-time, then consider using `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

The size of array should be a known constant in compile time, so that compiler can allocate correct memory for that array on the stack. Remember that such a declare is for stack variable. If you do want dynamic array, try std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the size of an array using numbers, #define or `const unsigned int`.  Otherwise they are considered variable length arrays.

Example:

```
const unsigned int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 14;
double my_array[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
```